# How can i tell PHP to fetch and post username on a comment?

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie on PHP but I need help, I want during a post of a comment to fetch the username and image from its database and insert it to the logged-in user who want to comment.

Here is my code

```
<?php
include('dbconnect.php');
$error = '';
$username = '';
$post = '';

$username = $_POST["username"];
$user_image = $_POST["user_image"];
$post = $_POST["post"];
$time = $_POST["time"];

if(empty($_POST["post"]))
{
$error .= '<p class="text-danger">Empty post!</p>';
}
else 
{
$post = $_POST["post"];
}

if($error == '')
{
$query = "
INSERT INTO comments
(comment_id, username, user_image, post, time)
VALUES (:comment_id, :username, :user_image, :post, :time)";
$statement = $con->prepare($query);
$statement->execute(
    array(
    ':comment_id' => '0',
    ':post' => $post,
    ':username' => $username
    ':user_image' => $user_image,
    ':post' => $post,
    'time' = $time
    )

    );
    $error = '<label class="text-success">Comment Added</label>';
}

$data= array(
'error' => $error
);

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: and what's the problem with your code?

Comment: I don;t know how to tell it to fetch username of the commenting user at the top

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Surely you're not just looking for `echo $username`?

Comment: Where is your username stored?  Why not just retrieve the user name from the DB ?  Or use your $_SESSION variable?

Comment: Users are in the database , am trying to create a simple comment system, of which users will be sharing their view, so i want to when a user is replying or adding a new comment his name should be added at his comment

Comment: So, is your question "How do I set a variable with the user name of the user who is currently logged in"?

Comment: yes, exactly Bleach

Comment: Do you currently display the user name of the user who is currently logged in anywhere on the screen of your main site?  If not, can you post your user login code?

Comment: I assume the username is set somewhere in your main page.  Read about submitting hidden variables in php forms.  Pass the user name from your main page to your code above using a hidden input type.